# Add vertical segments to a dynamic barplot ggplot-plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to make a dynamic plot, i.e. that I move the time slider and shows me the values for `XVAR` and `YVAR` in other time, I already got that. What I additionally need is that those points in the plot have a vertical segment to their respective height, i.e. from this

[image: Plot]

To this:

[image]

I've been told that `geom_segment()` could do that but I don't understand how to manage the `xend` and `yend` parameters such that the positions of the segments are correct.

Here's my code so far:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

XVAR<-seq(from=1,to=10)
Time<-seq(from=1,to=10)
dat2<-expand_grid(XVAR,Time)
set.seed(1)
dat2$YVAR<-runif(100,0,10)

pl <- 
ggplot(dat2, aes(x=XVAR,y=YVAR, frame = Time)) +
geom_point()

ggplotly(pl)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment` like this.

```
pl <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x=XVAR,y=YVAR, frame = Time)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = XVAR, xend = XVAR, y = 0, yend = YVAR), color = "red")

ggplotly(pl)
```

[image]